# Probability question, exponentially distributed with rate one

Tags: probability-distributions

Currently struggling with this question:
Have no idea where to start. This is for my probability course.

Assume that the time between emissions from a radioactive source are independent
and exponentially distributed with rate one. Each of these emissions
are detected by a Geiger counter with probability p. Compute the density of
the distribution of the time between detections of particles, and identify the
distribution by name.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Let $N$ denote the number of emissions it takes for the Geiger counter to detect an emission. Note that this is a random variable with geometric$(p)$ distribution. Next, let $X_1,X_2,\ldots$ be the sequence of exponentially$(\lambda)$ distributed times between emissions. Then the random variable of interest is
$$
X = \sum_{i=1}^{N}X_i,
$$
which is gamma$(N,\lambda)$ distributed. Do you know how to proceed from here?

Comment: I'm a little unsure as I cannot find anything on my lectures about this and I struggle with thinking generally. Wouldn't I need a pmf as well?